# MySQL Should each Database be managed by a different user?

Tags: mysql, debian

Should I have a different MySQL user for each database so that if someone gets access to a mysql user they cannot effect the others?

If so how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a principle called "separation of privileges", which reduces the impact of an intrusion.

you can do something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or you can provide some subset of privileges using a command similar to this;

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP
     ON mydatabase.*
     TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

The privileges supported by MySQL (5.1) are documented here;
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: If I am currently running all databases as root user, how do I remove the privileges from that user so I can create new users for each db.

Comment: do  you mean that you are running the databases as a `root` system user, or that each user connects to the database as root i.e. `mysql -uroot -psomepassword somedatabase`?

Comment: if its the latter, then create a user and password for each database, and distribute that information to your customers. When you are happy that they have migrated to the per-database user accounts, change the root password.

Comment: Yeah i do mysql -uroot -psomepassword somedatabase

Comment: the `root` user should always exist with full privileges, but its that normal day-to-day access should not being using it!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not me, someone has a hang-over and down-voting? one of my other answers is downvoted (rather harshly I thought)